# An RLC circuit with the capacitor connected in parallel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

Consider the following circuit, where the switch is left open for a long time:

[image]

What happens with the switch is closed?  There's certainly a potential difference across the capacitor, which also means that there's that same potential difference across the wire.  I thought that would be a short circuit.  What exactly happens?

$$V=6 \, \text{Volts}, \quad R=3\,\Omega, \quad L=8\,\text{mH}, \quad C=0.4\,\mu\text{F} \, .$$

Comment: Please be more specific than "for a long time". How long? With the switch open this is a damped oscillator which will lose energy to the resistor as time goes on. If we wait a "long" enough time, the energy will be gone and then nothing interesting happens if you close the switch.

Comment: @DanielSank "For a long time" means infinitely long.  Since the voltage source is not oscillatory, doesn't the capacitor charge up?

Comment: @DanielSank I think the question assumes that it charges up.  I'm not sure what's going to happen after the switch is displaced from 1 to 2.

Comment: Oh, woops, you're right. After a long time there will be no oscillating current, but there will be a voltage $V_0$ across the capacitor. Sorry about the misinformation above.

Comment: Yes, that shorts the capacitor, but the discharge isn't instantaneous. What do you think happens? Do you know how a charged capacitor responds to forced changes? Do you know what happens when you try to change the current in an inductor?  You should continue to think about this step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capacitor is a red herring and is irrelevant to the question.  When the switch is open for a long time, there is no current thru the resistor and inductor, and no voltage across them.  The capacitor is charged to the full supply voltage.

When the switch is closed, the capacitor is discharged instantly.  That can't happen exactly that way in real life because there will always be at least some resistance, but either way the capacitor discharges "quickly".

Now we simply have a resistor and inductor connected in series to a voltage source.  The only relevant initial condition is that the inductor current is zero.  The current will now ramp up, assymptotically approaching the voltage divided by the resistance:

$$I = (1 - e^{-tR/L})  V_o / R \, .$$

Comment: Please use mathjax for equations. It's much easier to read than HTML.

Comment: @Dan: I don't agree that it's easier to read than HTML, and HTML certainly a lot easier to write.  Mathjax also causes trouble with some versions of some browsers.  After your edit it looks the same as what I had.  Mathjax makes sense for more complicated equations, like with square roots, significant stuff above and below a divide line, etc.  However, in this case, it adds nothing.  I'd also have to look up mathjax, whereas I know the HTML, so that's what I'm going to keep on writing.

Answer (score 1):

After a long time, the capacitor charges up to the voltage $V_{0}$, with no current flowing.  (It is easy to verify that the sum of the voltages around the loop is zero in this case.)  When you short out the capacitor, it discharges instantly.  Then the capacitor voltage, which has been holding back the current flow across the other elements, is no longer present.  Therefore, current will begin to flow.  Since the capacitor is shorted out, what you have is effectively an RL circuit starting from zero current, and $I(t)$ follows the standard solution for that system.

Answer (score 0):

Before the switch is closed, the capacitor would have been charged to $V=6$ volts and there would be no current in the circuit.

When the switch is closed, the capacitor will be short circuited. There will be a large current in the switch branch (it will increase rapidly from 0 continously ; there won't be a jump suddenly). This current will consist of a DC component $V/R = 6/3 = 2 A$ and an oscillating component exponentially decaying to 0. The oscillating current will go to 0 and the capacitor will discharge. After a long time the current will be $2 A$ in the switch branch and $0$ in the capacitor branch.

Comment: hmm im not sure, can you find the problem with my reasoning:

the capacitor is shorted --> there's infinite amount of current flowing across the capacitor --> the capacitor discharges instantly.

Comment: This answer is correct if there's some resistance or inductance in the switch. That should be explained explicitly.